# Is it possible to create an AspectJ Pointcut from a Springframework AOP Pointcut?

Tags: java, spring-aop

I have an implementation of the `org.springframework.aop.Pointcut`, which is
implemented as:

```
public class MySillyPointcut implements org.springframework.aop.Pointcut {
    @Override
    public ClassFilter getClassFilter() {
        return ClassFilter.TRUE;
    }

    @Override
    public MethodMatcher getMethodMatcher() {
        return MethodMatcher.TRUE;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to create an AspectJ style pointcut which uses the behaviour from my pointcut? Such as:

```
@org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut("getPointcut()")
public void mySillyPointcut() {
}

public org.springframework.aop.Pointcut getPointcut() {
    return new MySillyPointcut();
}
```

So that I can create an advice that matches `mySillyPointcut()`

```
@Before("MyPointcuts.mySillyPointcut()")
public void sillyPointcut(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    LOGGER.info("Hello world!");
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have create an instance of `org.springframework.aop.support.annotation.AnnotationMatchingPointcut` with the arguments (null, MyAnnotation, true), which looks at parent classes. I have used a pointcut to find `execution(* com.mycompany..*(..))` and inside the advice, put `AopUtils.canApply(myPointcut, joinPoint...)`, I want to avoid the extra call to AopUtils.canApply, to tidy up my code.

Comment: This is incomprehensible. Maybe you should provide a full [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including a test showing what is expected and what happens instead. And BTW, doing AOP manually like this instead of just learning about and relying on how it is done by Spring AOP or AspectJ (whatever you want too use) feels like a bad idea to me. How will anyone be able to maintain and bugfix this application in 6 months from now, including yourself?

Comment: Is `execution(* com.mycompany..*(..)) && @annotation(MyAnnotation)` not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

When you use AspectJ expression, it is actually creating `AspectJExpressionPointcut`, which is an implementation of `org.springframework.aop.Pointcut`.

Perhaps what you're looking for is:

- your custom `org.springframework.aop.Pointcut` +
- your custom `org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor` +
- `org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor`

Here's [an example](https://github.com/yihtserns/test-spring-boot-aop/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/yihtserns/test/spring/boot/aop/Main.java#L19).